# FabricJS click event

Tags: gwt, canvas, fabricjs

I'm building a chart library on top of `FabricJS` canvas library. So far everything is working well as seen on this image:

[image]

However, I have started implementing `click` events and have bumped into a problem. For some reason click event is not working fully - it works on some regions and on some others it doesn't. For example, for bottom plot area (`<div>` with `<canvas>` within), click event works very awkward: When I click on green region it says that I have clicked the purple one while first 100 odd pixels of blue region don't emit click event :(. On the other hand top plot area works perfectly.

I have fully read the whole documentation on `FabricJS` and am aware of its pitfall but I somehow fail to see why this is happening. I have seen that people invoke `path.setCoord()` on order to refresh path coordinates, but that did not help.

One more thing, since I'm writing `GWT` module I needed to write `JSNI` wrappers in `JS` but I believe that I did it correct.

**Have I maybe overlooked something about `FabricJS`?**

UPDATE:

<kbd>Generated HTML:</kbd> [image]

<kbd>Bounding box - blue region in lower plot area</kbd>

[image]

The exact same bounding box is on upper blue region :-/

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the actual example. What's the bounding area of those shapes? That's the area that reacts to events in Fabric.

Comment: Also, it's `setCoords` not `setCoord` (not sure if typo here or in code)

Comment: @kangax Thanks for answering. That was a typo - I meant `setCoords()`. I will try to isolate bounding box data for blue region. Beginning to suspect that relative positioning of "plot areas" has something to do with this mess. I have  updated the question with generated HTML: Both `<DIV>`s are relatively positioned while `<CANVAS>`es have absolute positioning...

Comment: I isolated bounding box and, considering that lower plot area is separate `<DIV>` with `<CANVAS>`, these values seem expected, right?

Comment: So looks like canvases overlap each other, right?

Comment: Not according to Firebug (while hovering mouse over the tags). But values do seems very weird...

Comment: Did you try canvas.calcOffset()?

Comment: Ah, I didn't. I will do that and let you know it that did help :)

Comment: Hey @Kienz. I've tried that and it seems it did the trick! :) Can you please add an answer so I can mark it as resolution? :) Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: That solved a bunch of mouse offset and bounding problems for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `canvas.calcOffset()` to recalculate the correct position of your canvas element.